# Magento 2: Use of ObjectManager in Controller

Tags: magento2, object-manager, service-contract

Let's say I want to load a order item in a controller. I can use:

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\item')->load($id);
```

I see this happening in a lot of free and commercial modules. Even do everywhere on the forums they say Object manager is discouraged. Should I still use a service contract, even do the code is much more complex?

```
<?php namespace Xxx\xxx\Helper;

class GetOrderItemById
{
  private $orderRepository;
  private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemRepository $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
  ){
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
  }

  function getOrderItem($id)
  {
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
      ->addFilter('id', $id, 'eq')->create();
    $orderItem = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have edited my controller class:

```
<?php namespace Xxx\Xxx\Controller\Adminhtml\Save;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    private $orderRepository;
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemRepository $orderRepository,
      \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ){
      $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
      $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
      $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
      if (isset($post)) {

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
          ->addFilter('quote_item_id', $post['quote_item_id'], 'eq')->create();
        $orderItem = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();

        foreach ($orderItem as $item) {
          $return['item_id'] = ($item->getParentItemId() != NULL ? $item->getParentItemId() : $item->getId());
          $return['order_id'] = $item->getOrderId();
          var_dump($return);
        }
    }
}
```

It returns:

```
2018/08/05 19:03:39 [error] 19724#19724: *775254 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Qxs\SerialCode\Controller\Adminhtml\Save\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemRepository, instance of Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context given, called in /data/web/magento2_staging/generated/code/Qxs/SerialCode/Controller/Adminhtml/Save/Index/Interceptor.php on line 14 and defined in /data/web/magento2_staging/app/code/Qxs/SerialCode/Controller/Adminhtml/Save/Index.php:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should look a little more like this, assuming that the $id variable represents an order item ID:

```
namespace Xxx\xxx\Helper;

class GetOrderItemById
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderItemRepository;

    /**
     * GetOrderItemById constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository
    ){
        $this->orderItemRepository   = $orderItemRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface
     */
    public function getOrderItem($id)
    {
        return $this->orderItemRepository->get($id);
    }
}
```

You should be passing the OrderItemRepositoryInterface into your constructor instead of a reference to the concrete class.

You are correct that the usage of the object manager is discouraged. I still have not found a single instance where it's necessary to use it. Additionally, the `->load()` method is deprecated. In order to guarantee that your code will continue to work, it is best to use methods declared in the interfaces.

Also, your Context constructor argument is never used and I also don't see that you extend any class so it is likely to be unnecessary.

Additionally, you should declare proper visibility on functions within your class.

---

In response to your updated question, what happened is that you updated the controller but the auto-generated class that lives in generated/code wasn't updated. Simply delete the generated/code directory and that issue should go away.

A few things about your constructor.

- You should not pass in the concrete class `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemRepository`. Instead, you should replace that with `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface`. You will still get the same class. By type-hinting the interface instead of the class name, you will receive the highest priority version of the interface, just in case it ever gets changed by you or some third party module.
- `$orderRepository` would be more appropriately named `$orderItemRepository` because that is in fact what you are invoking. The class your are injecting into your constructor is not an order repository.

In your execute function:

- You never check to see if array key quote_item_id exists in $post and you never check to see if post is actually an array. Both can throw a fatal error. It would be more efficient and safer to do it the way I recommend in the code posted below.
- Each order item is an instance of `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface`. You should use only methods that exist on the interface to guarantee that your code won't break. I am referring more specifically to `$item->getId()`. That method does not exist in the interface. Instead, use `$item->getItemId()`

You can copy and paste this example and it should work perfectly as-is. Just be sure to delete the generated/code directory.

```
    <?php

    namespace Xxx\Xxx\Controller\Adminhtml\Save;

    use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface;
    use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
    use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

    class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {
        /**
         * @var OrderItemRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $orderItemRepository;

        /**
         * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
         */
        private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

        /**
         * Index constructor.
         *
         * @param OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository
         * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder        $searchCriteriaBuilder
         * @param Context               $context
         */
        public function __construct(
            OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository,
            SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            Context $context
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);

            $this->orderItemRepository   = $orderItemRepository;
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue(
                OrderItemInterface::QUOTE_ITEM_ID
            );

            if ($itemId) {
                $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                    ->addFilter(OrderItemInterface::QUOTE_ITEM_ID, $itemId, 'eq');
                $orderItem      = $this->orderItemRepository->getList(
                    $searchCriteria->create()
                )->getItems();

                /** @var OrderItemInterface $item */
                foreach ($orderItem as $item) {
                    $return['item_id']  = ($item->getParentItemId() != null ? $item->getParentItemId() : $item->getItemId());
                    $return['order_id'] = $item->getOrderId();
                    var_dump($return);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On another note, a helpful note that you'll thank me for ages, I see you are using var_dump. Your life will be not only easier, but you'll more quickly understand the Magento architecture if you start using xDebug instead. I have create a 7-part YouTube tutorial series on how to install and use it. [xDebug + PhpStorm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDbF3UmV8jQ&list=PL7cMNPx-nzyiKmGE2A08S2PF5MKfBJF3n)

Comment: Agree with this answer, but I would not use Helper namespace. It looks like a literally ported code from Magento 1. It's better to place such code to Model where Magento 2 Team suggests to place such logic. Also, it's possible to have additional namespaces in the root of module directory. However, it can be concerned on Magento Marketplace module code review.

Comment: @RomanGlushko you are correct. I actually don’t even see the need for this class to exist at all unless he is gonna have a bunch more functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited this code a bit because I used it to retrieve an order item based on the quote_item_id. Will this always be done in a model? Could I also use it in a controller?

Comment: It can also be used in a controller if needed. If this works for you please don’t forget to mark the answer as accepted and if you have any other questions please let me know . Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, yes I will let the discussion go on a little bit an wil accept the awnser asap!

Comment: I have updated my question with the repository used in my controller. Could you check it? Also what do you mean by 'declare proper visibility on functions within your class' ?

Comment: Driving right now but I’ll check it out as soon as I get home

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: After emptying var/generated I got 2018/08/07 16:14:31 [error] 19723#19723: *1279151 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on null in /data/web/magento2_staging/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:255

Comment: lemme update the constructor. we are supposed to call the parent constructor

Comment: updated the constructor in my answer

Comment: Yeah! I was just fixing that! Many thanks, gratefull forever and ever! I wil most definitly check out your youtube videos. First will have to get my vargant/virtualbox up and running.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Actually, vagrant/virtualbox can be difficult to manage. I wrote a tutorial on how to run M2 on docker. The box that you install with the tut actually has xdebug on it. I wrote the first paragraph of the xdebug tutorial this morning. Should be finished some time soon. https://www.magemodule.com/all-things-magento/magento-2-tutorials/docker-magento-2-development/